# Resizing RAID-1 devices after dd clone

Tags: raid1, dd, clone

I had 2 x 250 GB disks with 3 md devices - raid 1 setup on them. One of them is for /. I dd-cloned those disks to another 2 x 2 TB SSDs. What is the best solution to increase the raid device sizes?  "mdadm --grow /dev/mdX --size max" is not working.

Metadata is 0.90 as per /etc/mdadm.conf .

Comment: I would create a new RAID array on the SSDs, create a new filesystem and then copy all files from the old one and make it bootable again. Reason: A 250GB array indiciates an old system, and it would better to create a clean and new filesystem/array.

Comment: It would be very difficult to reinstall the software running anew, as the software developer who made it is now defunct. Therefore I can resort only to cloning tactic, as I also don't know what is where anymore.

Comment: It's not so difficult. Attach the 2 SSD to your server, boot it, maybe create partition tables if needed, create a new RAID array, create same type filesystem, mount the filesystem into an empty directory, like `/mnt/`, adjust `/etc/fstab`, reboot into emergency mode (mainenance mode, runlevel 1), check if the new array-FS is auto mounted, copy all files from your old array-FS `/` to new array-FS `/mnt` using `cp -aux / /mnt/`, prepare to chroot to `/mnt/`, then chroot to it, update GRUB, write bootsector into MBR if needed, adjust config files for switched root, reboot, test and bugfix.